# Run a command and use the same value in a playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

i want to execute the below command in ansible playboo, and then i want to take the UUID value for /sdc and then i have to create LVM. Can anyone please suggest the ideas?

```
 blkid /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc: UUID="F0EDIZ-3WSs-kNj2-43eW-NY1G-xiux-x5QIep" TYPE="LVM2_member"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the device information from the facts variable `ansible_devices`. Example playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_devices.sda
```

In order to create LVM volumes you have to use the [`lvol` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lvol_module.html).

Comment: Thanks. From the output of the above ansible_devices.sda, i want to take scsi-360022480d20b7b64c7b977b03cb1d091 and create LVM and map that to /dev/sdc..